# Password protected tickbox

Tags: vba

I would like to have a code that does the following
If a tickbox is checked, the tickbox is disabled and grayed out. 
I achieved this via the following code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
CheckBox1.Value = False
CheckBox1.Enabled = False
```

But I would like to have the possibility to edit this tickbox if a password is entered. 
 How can I embed this to the above code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    If TextBox1.Text = "secret" Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Cells(1, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If TextBox1.Text = "secret" Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CheckBox1.Value = False
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Auto select A1 when you press enter on the textbox, so it will lost focus.

Check password when the textbox lost focus, enable the checkbox if password is correct.

Check password when you click on the checkbox, if password incorrect it will be disabled.

Comment: why the tickbox grays out even if it is not ticked?(I would like to have it gray once it is ticked...) Is it also possible to confirm the password when enter is clicked ?As now i need to confirm this by clicking on any other cell

Comment: @Adam Answer updated. For your first question, it is just because the initial stat of your checkbox is disabled, enable it first by entering the correct password, after that, it will be disabled only if you enter the wrong password AND click on the checkbox.